# Test if a 3D Point is with an extruded "2.5D" Polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I need to check if a point given as x,y,z coordinates is within an extruded 2.5D Polygon. I thought it should be possible to achieve using a 2D point-in-polygon check (e.g. [1]) with additional distance checks.

I'd like to avoid creating meshes for the polygon for performance reasons. Is it possible?

[1] [How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon/2922778#2922778)

Comment: I think some additional information would be helpful. What is your input? Is it an image or do you have vertex coordinates? Have you tried your idea? What were the results?

Comment: My input is vector geo data in cartesian coordinates. I‘m also trying to create a polyhedra from the polygon, I have posted another question for that. I have no idea how to construct polyhedra from a polygon with an extrusion. Thus, I haven‘t tried.

Comment: If you have 2d coordinates (or can project them onto the XY plane) with `Z = 0`, then extrusion is simply duplicating those points with a different `Z` value. Again, sample input data, and expected output would be helpful.